# Adding text to the end of a line in bash with sed

Tags: linux, bash

I have variable in my script called:

```
 VAR=/opt/sbin/test
```

and I want to append a text for example 'text' at the end of the line with a space and then run the line as

```
 /opt/sbin/test text
```

Comment: Do you want to run the /opt/sbin/text from within the script with the variable VAR?

Comment: yes @moran and only for this line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the command you are looking for is:

```
VAR=/opt/sbin/test
VAR="$VAR text"
BLAH=$(${VAR})
```

The above will set $VAR to /opt/sbin/test text and then BLAH=$(${VAR}) will execute it.

Comment: No problem. I've had to do similar things in the past. :)